# Symfony yaml config: execute plain php code

Tags: symfony

Symfony framework 4.4

Here is my `config/services.yaml` file:

```
parameters:
    ...
    app.dogstatsd.config:
        host: 'some_host_name.domain.com'
        global_tags:
            node: 'hostname'
            env: '%env(APP_ENV)%'

services:
    ...
    DataDog\DogStatsd:
        arguments: ['%app.dogstatsd.config%']
```

I need `node` to be equal to PHP gethostname() function result.

On the server side::

```
$ hostname
homestead
```

So, how can I get hostname value from the yaml-config?

I have found the solution:

```
    env(HOSTNAME): '../config/.runtime-evaluated.php'
    app.dogstatsd.config:
        host: 'some_host_name.domain.com'
        global_tags:
            node: '%env(require:HOSTNAME)%'
            env: '%env(APP_ENV)%'
```

where

```
$ cat config/.runtime-evaluated.php'
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

return gethostname();
```

It looks quite ugly for me...
Does somebody have another solution?

Answer (score -1):

### Edit: What you're doing on-hingsight is actually fine. I think on reflection it's absolutely okay. I'll leave my comments below anyway.

I don't like that you are trying to inject the full config to a service. Why bother when you've said it's variable.. But for the arguments sake, let's say that you HAVE to.... at that point, what you are trying to do it probably makes sense to create a DependencyInjection Extension which allows you to extend the value of another bundles configuration option.

Maybe take a look at it here: https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/bundles/prepend_extension.html

For example, what you can do is create a file.. pick your own naming and preferred bundle to add it to....

`// src/AppDDoggerBundle/DI/DDWhateverYouWantToCallMeExtension.php`

```
public function prepend(ContainerBundle $container){
   // Get existing DD Bundle Config.. 
   // (I don't know what the Bundle Alias is called)
   $container->loadFromExtension('ddstat', [
      'key' => 'value'
   ]);
   
}
```

Would it not make more sense to have a Helper Service which you use to access DDStatt instead?

For example...

```
<?php

/**
 * Created by Helpful Stackoverflow User.
 * User: layke
 * Date: 02/12/20
 * Time: 22:17.
 */

namespace App\DataDogBundle\Service;

    use DataDog\DogStatsd;

    /**
     * Class DDStatter.
     *
     * @method timing(string $stat, float $time, float $sampleRate, array | string $tags)
     * @method microtiming(string $stat, float $time, float $sampleRate, array | string $tags)
     * @method gauge(string $stat, float $value, float $sampleRate, array | string $tags)
     * @method histogram(string $stat, float $value, float $sampleRate, array | string $tags)
     * @method distribution(string $stat, float $value, float $sampleRate, array | string $tags)
     * @method set(string $stat, float $value, float $sampleRate, array | string $tags)
     * @method increment(string | array $stat, float $sampleRate, array | string $tags, float $value)
     * @method decrement(string | array $stat, float $sampleRate, array | string $tags, float $value)
     * @method updateStats(string | array $stat, int $delta, float $sampleRate, array | string $tags)
     * @method serialize_tags(array | string $tags)
     * @method normalize_tags(mixed $tags)
     * @method send(array $data, float $sampleRate, array | string $tags)
     */
    class DDStatter
    {
        private $statd;

        /**
         * DDStatter constructor.
         */
        public function __construct(?string $dataDogApiKey, ?string $dataDogAppKey)
        {
            $this->statd = new DogStatsd([
                'api_key' => $dataDogApiKey,
                'app_key' => $dataDogAppKey,
            ]);
        }

        public function __call($method, $args)
        {
            return call_user_func_array([$this->statd, $method], $args);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your solutions quite cumbersome too and I am surprised about this situation.